# How can i make IF in javascript false?

Tags: javascript

I m trying to block certain countries in my website.

This script will only load my website in the US, CA(Canada) and GB(Great Britain) and the alert will show if you're accessing in other countries.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var geo = disp();
if (geo[0] != 'US' && geo[0] != 'CA' && geo[0] != 'GB'){
   alert('Sorry this site is only accessible from the USA, Canada 
          and Great Britain');
   window.location = ('http://www.yahoo.com');
}
</script>
```

But I want to show the alert on  a particular country.

What is the opposite of IF..?

Or How can I make the statement false..?

Comment: Javascript could be turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im trying to block a certain country in my website

```
if (geo[0] == 'The country') {
    alert('Not allowed');
    window.location = 'http://google.com/';
}
```

You don't need an else if you just want to block one country.

Answer (score 6):

Blocking a site in Javascript ?

Do you realize how useless this is, you can only block from a backend using IP or whatever.
But client side this is useless. Visitors just have to disable JS and tada! there are on your website.

So what you could do it use a library on your backend using [geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite)'s database to block accoring to ips.

Here is one way to do it with [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/).
And here directly into [Apache](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block_htaccess.php).

Blocking by IP is not perfect but that is as good as you can do it.

Comment: Yeah well I mean I assume he's also doing something server side, and this is just so that it looks pretty

Comment: I know this not an the wanted answers but this is a really bad approach to the problem.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i also have a script (noscript) that if they DISABLE JAVASCRIPT nothing will show on my website :)

Comment: @JannaRoxas You have a script in the noscript tag?!?

Answer (score 1):

Just use "else":

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var geo = disp();
if (geo[0] != 'US' && geo[0] != 'CA' && geo[0] != 'GB'){
   alert('Sorry this site is only accessible from the USA, Canada and Great Britain');
   window.location = ('http://www.yahoo.com');
} else {
   // some other stuff
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just

```
if(){
   // if the condition in if is true  
}else{
  // if the condition of if false
}
```

or use the `!` (NOT) operator

```
if(!condition){
   // if the condition in if is false
 }
```

and the blocking of other site by JavaScript is not a good even worse idea to choose . it should  be done at server side

Answer (score 0):

The 'opposite' of if is else.

```
 if(condition) {
   [This gets executed if condition is true]
}
else {   //or if(!condition)
   [This gets executed if condition is false]
}
```

You need to look over some basic javascript tutorials before posting questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

If a client scripts are disabled on a browser then your code won't work at all..So most probably you have to change your logic or strategy..

**What You can do is:**

You can check that via `IP Addresses`.

Comment: i also have a script (noscript) that if they DISABLE JAVASCRIPT nothing will show on my website :